# Django: Fetch logged in user information from database and show them in html

Tags: python, django

I've menaged to create a form that allow me to save my website user information in the database. Right now I'd like to create a page where the saved info are showed to my user also. Of course I want my user to be able to see only their own information. This is what I came up with until now, it doesn't wotk and unfortunly I'm not getting any error, just a blanck html page aside for the title. How can I solve this? Thank you all!

**model.py**

```
class Info(models.Model):
   first_name = models.CharField(max_length=120)
   last_name = models.CharField(max_length=120)
   phone = models.CharField(max_length=10)
```

**views.py**

```
def show(request):
   info = Info.objects.all().filter(first_name=request.user)
   return render(request, 'profile/show.html', {'info': info})
```

**info.html**

```
<h1> Profile  </h1>
</br></br> 
{% if user.is_authenticated %}


{% for info in info %}

   <li>First Name: {{ info.first_name }}</li>
   <li>Last Name: {{ info.last_name }}</li>
   <li>Phone Number: {{ info.phone }}</li>


{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: The issue because of `request.user` uses Django default `User` model

Comment: How did you save this information of that user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`request.user` type is `User`. So when you are passing it to `first_name`, doesn't seem right

You can do the followings:

```py
def show(request):
    user_first_name = request.user.first_name
    info = Info.objects.all().filter(first_name=user_first_name)
    return render(request, 'profile/show.html', {'info': info})
```

Answer (score 1):

**The filter method apply on queryset in Django return a list not an single object.**

You can fix your issue like this :

```
def show(request):
    # You can use id to get a single user like bellow
    info_id = Info.objects.get(user_id=request.user.id)
    # Or use the `first` method of queryset to retrieve the first element in the list
    info_name = Info.objects.all().filter(first_name=request.user.first_name).first()
    return render(request, 'profile/show.html', {'info': info})
```